# Using boost to calculate days. Worked just fine in linux on version boost 1.74 but giving me error in MacOS in version boost 1.76

Tags: c++, unix, boost

### Issue

I am trying to calculate days based on a particular day of the week using boost 1.76 on macOS with clang 13.0.0. The same code was running just fine on ubuntu with g++ 6.0 using C++14.

### Code Lines

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
```

---

### Error

```
In file included from /Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/example/src/save_to_csv/main.cpp:6:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp:24:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/time_formatters.hpp:12:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp:31:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/date_facet.hpp:17:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:38:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/functions.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/size.hpp:25:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/utility.hpp:15:
/opt/local/include/boost/utility/base_from_member.hpp:146:5: error: unknown type name 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_BOOST_PP_REM'
   BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO( 2, BOOST_PP_INC(BOOST_BASE_FROM_MEMBER_MAX_ARITY),
   ^
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:35:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_, BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_P, 4))
                                ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:22:32: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT(a, b) BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b)
                              ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:29:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT_I'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b) a ## b
                                ^
note: (skipping 3 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp:38:37: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1(c, m, d) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_I(c, m, d)
                                   ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp:43:39: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_I'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_I(c, m, d) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_ ## c(m, d)
                                     ^
<scratch space>:17:1: note: expanded from here
BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_BOOST_PP_REM
^ 
In file included from /Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/example/src/save_to_csv/main.cpp:6:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp:24:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/time_formatters.hpp:12:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp:31:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/date_facet.hpp:17:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:38:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/functions.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/size.hpp:25:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/utility.hpp:15:
/opt/local/include/boost/utility/base_from_member.hpp:146:5: error: unknown type name 'BOOST_PP_SUB_P'
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:35:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_, BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_P, 4))
                                ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:22:32: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT(a, b) BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b)
                              ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:29:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT_I'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b) a ## b
                                ^
note: (skipping 1 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:49:49: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_1'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_1(f, l, m, dt) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_D_1(BOOST_PP_DEC(BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_WHILE_P, 256)), f, l, m, dt)
                                               ^
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:81:75: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_D_1'
#    define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_D_1(d, f, l, m, dt) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1(BOOST_PP_SUB_D(d, l, f), BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_M_1, (d, f, m, dt))
                                                                         ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/sub.hpp:44:84: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_SUB_D'
#    define BOOST_PP_SUB_D(d, x, y) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, BOOST_PP_WHILE_ ## d(BOOST_PP_SUB_P, BOOST_PP_SUB_O, (x, y)))
                                                                                  ^
In file included from /Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/example/src/save_to_csv/main.cpp:6:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp:24:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/time_formatters.hpp:12:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp:31:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/date_facet.hpp:17:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:38:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/functions.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/size.hpp:25:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/utility.hpp:15:
/opt/local/include/boost/utility/base_from_member.hpp:146:5: error: unknown type name 'BOOST_PP_SUB_O'
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:35:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_, BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_P, 4))
                                ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:22:32: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT(a, b) BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b)
                              ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:29:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT_I'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b) a ## b
                                ^
note: (skipping 1 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:49:49: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_1'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_1(f, l, m, dt) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_D_1(BOOST_PP_DEC(BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_WHILE_P, 256)), f, l, m, dt)
                                               ^
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:81:75: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_D_1'
#    define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_D_1(d, f, l, m, dt) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1(BOOST_PP_SUB_D(d, l, f), BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_M_1, (d, f, m, dt))
                                                                         ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/sub.hpp:44:100: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_SUB_D'
#    define BOOST_PP_SUB_D(d, x, y) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, BOOST_PP_WHILE_ ## d(BOOST_PP_SUB_P, BOOST_PP_SUB_O, (x, y)))
                                                                                                  ^
In file included from /Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/example/src/save_to_csv/main.cpp:6:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp:24:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/time_formatters.hpp:12:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp:31:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/date_facet.hpp:17:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:38:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/functions.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/size.hpp:25:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/utility.hpp:15:
/opt/local/include/boost/utility/base_from_member.hpp:146:33: error: expected ')'
   BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO( 2, BOOST_PP_INC(BOOST_BASE_FROM_MEMBER_MAX_ARITY),
                               ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/inc.hpp:22:29: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_INC'
#    define BOOST_PP_INC(x) BOOST_PP_INC_I(x)
                           ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/inc.hpp:28:28: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_INC_I'
# define BOOST_PP_INC_I(x) BOOST_PP_INC_ ## x
                          ^
<scratch space>:120:1: note: expanded from here
BOOST_PP_INC_10
^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/inc.hpp:40:26: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_INC_10'
# define BOOST_PP_INC_10 11
                        ^
/opt/local/include/boost/utility/base_from_member.hpp:146:5: note: to match this '('
   BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO( 2, BOOST_PP_INC(BOOST_BASE_FROM_MEMBER_MAX_ARITY),
   ^
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:35:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_, BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_P, 4))
                                ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:22:32: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT(a, b) BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b)
                              ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:29:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT_I'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b) a ## b
                                ^
note: (skipping 1 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:49:49: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_1'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_1(f, l, m, dt) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_D_1(BOOST_PP_DEC(BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_WHILE_P, 256)), f, l, m, dt)
                                               ^
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:81:75: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_D_1'
#    define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_D_1(d, f, l, m, dt) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1(BOOST_PP_SUB_D(d, l, f), BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_M_1, (d, f, m, dt))
                                                                         ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/sub.hpp:44:116: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_SUB_D'
#    define BOOST_PP_SUB_D(d, x, y) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, BOOST_PP_WHILE_ ## d(BOOST_PP_SUB_P, BOOST_PP_SUB_O, (x, y)))
                                                                                                                  ^
In file included from /Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/example/src/save_to_csv/main.cpp:6:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp:24:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/time_formatters.hpp:12:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp:31:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/date_facet.hpp:17:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:38:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/functions.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/size.hpp:25:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/utility.hpp:15:
/opt/local/include/boost/utility/base_from_member.hpp:146:33: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
   BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO( 2, BOOST_PP_INC(BOOST_BASE_FROM_MEMBER_MAX_ARITY),
                               ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/inc.hpp:22:29: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_INC'
#    define BOOST_PP_INC(x) BOOST_PP_INC_I(x)
                           ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/inc.hpp:28:28: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_INC_I'
# define BOOST_PP_INC_I(x) BOOST_PP_INC_ ## x
                          ^
<scratch space>:120:1: note: expanded from here
BOOST_PP_INC_10
^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/inc.hpp:40:26: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_INC_10'
# define BOOST_PP_INC_10 11
                        ^
In file included from /Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/example/src/save_to_csv/main.cpp:6:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp:24:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/time_formatters.hpp:12:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp:31:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/date_facet.hpp:17:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:38:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/functions.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/size.hpp:25:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/utility.hpp:15:
/opt/local/include/boost/utility/base_from_member.hpp:146:5: error: unknown type name 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_M_1'
   BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO( 2, BOOST_PP_INC(BOOST_BASE_FROM_MEMBER_MAX_ARITY),
   ^
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:35:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_, BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_P, 4))
                                ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:22:32: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT(a, b) BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b)
                              ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:29:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT_I'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b) a ## b
                                ^
<scratch space>:119:1: note: expanded from here
BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_1
^
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:49:49: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_1'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_1(f, l, m, dt) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_D_1(BOOST_PP_DEC(BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_WHILE_P, 256)), f, l, m, dt)
                                               ^
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:81:100: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_D_1'
#    define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_D_1(d, f, l, m, dt) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1(BOOST_PP_SUB_D(d, l, f), BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_M_1, (d, f, m, dt))
                                                                                                  ^
In file included from /Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/example/src/save_to_csv/main.cpp:6:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp:24:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/time_formatters.hpp:12:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp:31:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/date_facet.hpp:17:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:38:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/functions.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/size.hpp:25:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/utility.hpp:15:
/opt/local/include/boost/utility/base_from_member.hpp:146:5: error: expected ')'
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:35:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_, BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_P, 4))
                                ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:22:32: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT(a, b) BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b)
                              ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:29:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT_I'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b) a ## b
                                ^
note: (skipping 3 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/dec.hpp:28:28: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_DEC_I'
# define BOOST_PP_DEC_I(x) BOOST_PP_DEC_ ## x
                          ^
<scratch space>:13:1: note: expanded from here
BOOST_PP_DEC_1
^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/dec.hpp:31:25: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_DEC_1'
# define BOOST_PP_DEC_1 0
                       ^
/opt/local/include/boost/utility/base_from_member.hpp:146:5: note: to match this '('
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:35:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_, BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_P, 4))
                                ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:22:32: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT(a, b) BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b)
                              ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:29:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT_I'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b) a ## b
                                ^
<scratch space>:119:1: note: expanded from here
BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_1
^
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:49:49: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_1'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_1(f, l, m, dt) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_D_1(BOOST_PP_DEC(BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_WHILE_P, 256)), f, l, m, dt)
                                               ^
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:81:129: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_D_1'
#    define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_D_1(d, f, l, m, dt) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1(BOOST_PP_SUB_D(d, l, f), BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_M_1, (d, f, m, dt))
                                                                                                                               ^
In file included from /Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/example/src/save_to_csv/main.cpp:6:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp:24:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/time_formatters.hpp:12:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp:31:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/date_facet.hpp:17:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:38:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/functions.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/size.hpp:25:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/utility.hpp:15:
/opt/local/include/boost/utility/base_from_member.hpp:146:5: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
   BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO( 2, BOOST_PP_INC(BOOST_BASE_FROM_MEMBER_MAX_ARITY),
   ^
/opt/local/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp:35:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO_, BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_P, 4))
                                ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:22:32: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT(a, b) BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b)
                              ^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:29:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT_I'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b) a ## b
                                ^
note: (skipping 3 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/dec.hpp:28:28: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_DEC_I'
# define BOOST_PP_DEC_I(x) BOOST_PP_DEC_ ## x
                          ^
<scratch space>:13:1: note: expanded from here
BOOST_PP_DEC_1
^
/Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/dependency/boost/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/dec.hpp:31:25: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_DEC_1'
# define BOOST_PP_DEC_1 0
                       ^
In file included from /Users/himanshugupta/Desktop/Niveshi/ccapi/example/src/save_to_csv/main.cpp:6:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp:24:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/time_formatters.hpp:12:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp:31:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/date_facet.hpp:17:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp:16:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:38:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/functions.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/range/size.hpp:25:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/utility.hpp:15:
/opt/local/include/boost/utility/base_from_member.hpp:147:32: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    BOOST_PRIVATE_CTR_DEF, _ )
                              ^
```

### Additional info

I think the issue is in these header files.
Currently, I am building my files using CMake 3.21 with clang 13 with boost 1.76 installed using `sudo port install boost`  and I believe code logic is fine as it worked on Linux just fine. Couldn't get anything about this error anywhere so asking here.
Let me know if I need to provide additional details.

Comment: Write a bug ticket. Make sure you include a [mcve], which is also mandatory for such questions here. Further, read the descriptions of the tags you applied, some of them really don't fit. That said, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt @Alan  I tried providing minimal reproducible example. But this is the issue whenever I use `boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp` it is giving me this error.
And it is the entire thing that comes whenever I invoke `posix_time.hpp` can't really minimise this error because I believe it has something to do with source code of boost which I haven't bothered with.
Anything else that I can do please let me know.

Comment: @HimanshuGupta that just means your minimal example is the single `#include` line. That's the entire point.

Comment: @sehe thanks. Please let me know if you can think of anything now.

Comment: So, in short, you are including a third-party header file and that causes the error. Again, see my initial suggestion. Additionally, check existing bug tickets as well, maybe there's already an existing fix.

Comment: What @Ulrich says. Specifically, does the error also occuer when you include just `boost/mpl/next_prior.hpp`? https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2017/03/233833.php

Comment: @sehe I have never used next_prior.hpp. But I looked into this and it is pretty similar to my error. But the solution given for that is not working for me.
The solution was to disable MS compatibility which I did but didn't work out.
Maybe I need to raise a bug ticket.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I checked in their GitHub issues page open and closed both. None of them has any explanation regarding this. So I raised a new issue over there

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly situation.
I am posting the solution if anyone like me end up in this same situation.

### Solution

I had multiple versions of boost installed in my system which I didn't realize until someone pointed out this mistake to me. And then everything worked like it is supposed.
So I had to uninstall one of the boost versions and that is it.